# Como resolver erro android Studio ao tentar reproduzir arquivo MID

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá.
Estou aprendendo android e estou tentando reproduzir um arquivo .MID em meu app.

Na activity Main tem este código:

```
package com.micsgsoftwares.exemploplayermusic;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.h001);
    }

    public void CliqueBotao(View v){

        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
    }
}
```

O arquivo h001 está na pasta raw do res.
Já coloquei outros arquivos, só que mp3, e não apresentou erro nenhum e reproduziu o arquivo.

O erro apresentado é o seguinte:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.examplesoftware.exemploplayermusic, PID: 4890
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examplesoftware.exemploplayermusic/com.examplesoftware.exemploplayermusic.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/h001.MID from drawable resource ID #0x7f0e0000
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/h001.MID from drawable resource ID #0x7f0e0000
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1315)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:937)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:920)
        at com.examplesoftware.exemploplayermusic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:426)
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1312)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:937) 
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:920) 
        at com.micsgsoftwares.exemploplayermusic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Gostaria que me ajudassem a corrigir estes erros.

---

EDIT

- Uso android 6.0 api 23.

Resolvi o problema parcialmente, convertendo os arquivos MID em mp3. Mais ainda gostaria de saber por que não consigo reproduzir arquivos MID no android  se na documentação do android studio diz que se pode reproduzir arquivos MID:
link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer?hl=pt-br#mediaplayer

> Um dos componentes mais importantes do framework de mídia é a classe
> MediaPlayer. Um objeto dessa classe pode buscar, decodificar e
> reproduzir áudio e vídeo com uma quantidade mínima de configuração.
> Ela é compatível com várias fontes de mídia diferentes, como:
>
> - Recursos locais
> - URIs internos, como um que você possa conseguir a partir de um resolvedor de conteúdo
> - URLs externos (streaming)
>
> Para ver uma lista de formatos de mídia compatíveis com o Android,
> consulte a página Formatos de mídia compatíveis.

Consultei a página Formatos de mídia compatíveis:

link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats?hl=pt-br#audio-codecs
[image: Documentação do Android diz que suporta MID]